# Redactor-rails gem issue on Heroku after upgrading to Rails 3.2.12 and json 1.7.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, redactor

I've upgraded some of the gems I use because of the recent Rails security issues.

I'm seeing an error after I push my app to heroku (push goes through fine, but the app never stops crashing):

```
2013-02-12T00:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.3/lib/redactor-rails.rb:30:in `document_model': uninitialized constant RedactorRails::Document (NameError)
2013-02-12T00:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.3/app/controller/redactor_rails/documents_controller.rb:2:in `<class:DocumentsController>'
2013-02-12T00:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redactor-rails-0.3.3/app/controller/redactor_rails/documents_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2013-02-12T00:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-02-12T00:12:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
```

I don't see this issue when I run the app locally. Locally, I'm on ruby 1.9.3-p194 but it looks like Heroku is on Ruby 1.9.1.

Any ideas on how I can go about fixing this?

Thanks,
Ringo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following if you are using 0.3.3 redactor-rails

```
rails generate redactor:install
```

This should generate the additional,

> app/uploaders/redactor_rails_document_uploader.rb
>
> app/models/redactor_rails/document.rb

else,

restrict redactor-rails to earlier version of 0.3.2 in your Gemfile as

```
gem 'redactor-rails', '0.3.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `ruby "1.9.3"` to your Gemfile and use Ruby 1.9.3 (patch 374, I think...). See here for more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

UPDATE: 
This actually looks like a bug with the Redactor-Rails gem: https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/issues/44

Comment: thanks for letting me know! unfortunately, even this hasn't helped. I have no clue why I seem to be the only person facing this issue.

Comment: can you share some of `app/controller/redactor_rails/documents_controller.rb` ? At least the top part

Comment: yep absolutely. here's a link to the file: https://github.com/SammyLin/redactor-rails/blob/master/app/controller/redactor_rails/documents_controller.rb